# how to limit the not all activity events to be visible for all employees

Tags: activities

Good day,

I have the following question how can I hide some activities not to be visible to all employees. Now the sharing settings for Account and Contact are Public Read/Write and for Activities are controlled by parent. The main idea is that there some internal events that shouldn't be visible. The solution that I think is possible is to change the sharing settings to Private for Account and Contact and after that via sharing rules to expand the access. If anybody knows something else as solution I would be happy to read it here?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_model_fields.htm&type=5

I think you got it. No ability to create sharing rules on activities themselves (and I don't believe Salesforce plans to add this per this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrFmAAK)) so you'll have to set up the parent to have the restriction/rules you'd like to apply to the activities on those objects.